# Irreducible Polynomials and $F^*$ notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

So in my lecture notes for an irreducible polynomial I have the following definition

> A non-zero polynomial $f \in F[X]$ is **irreducible** iff $f \notin F^*$ and if $f=gh$ then either $g \in F^*$ or $h \in F^*$, where $F^* = F \setminus \{0\} $

What I dont understand is this definition of $F^*$ and how it applies to the reasoning behind irreducible polynomials.

If someone could explain what it means for a polynomial to be an element of $F^*$ I'd be grateful!

Comment: It says $F*$ is $F$ without $0$

Comment: Yeah sorry I perhaps wasn't really clear, I understand the notation but not really how it applies to the defintion.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say $f\in F[X]$?   Or perhaps I am unclear as to what $F$ is.

Comment: Ah yes It does say that, sorry I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F^*$ is the set of units of $F[X]$.

Factorization in rings need to take units into consideration. For instance, when unique factorization holds, it holds only up to units. For example, in $\mathbb Z$, the units are $\pm1$ and unique factorization holds up to sign in. Otherwise, $2 \cdot 3 = (-2) \cdot (-3)$ would be two different factorizations of $6$. Or worse, $2=(-1)(-2)$ would say that $2$ is reducible (= not prime).

Bottom line: the definition of irreducible aims at elements that cannot be further decomposed, except for units.